# Synchronization of two devices using UART communication

Tags: synchronization, protocols

I wired up two devices using an UART interface (not RS-232, so no control lines).
Because of limited APIs and hardware access, there is no way to modify the
transmission scheme (e.g. modify parity or stop bit settings).
So all I have is the possibility to transfer bytes between two devices.

One device acts as a *master*, should initiate the connection
(set it up to a defined state), send commands two the client which responds with
a corresponding answer. The actual protocol is up to me, but it should include 
several commands with no arguments, arguments of a defined length (e.g. 3 bytes)
and binary data transmission of arbitrary length.

I defined a simple protocol where the first bytes contains a command number and the amount and type of parameters encoded as flags, so the client can be implemented as a simple state machine.

My problem is, that if the master looses the connection (e.g. due to a crash),
it cannot reset the client and bring it to a defined state, if the client is
currently waiting for command arguments or data of a binary transmission.

Some people used a 'blacklist' and e.g. defined the byte *0xFF* as reset
command wherever it appears, but this would break my requirement of arbitrary
binary transfers (or I would have to reencode the data).

Do you have any other idea how I can define the protocol so it allows the master
to reset the client no matter what *state* it currently is in
(what it already received)?

Comment: Do you have stringent timing requirements?

Comment: Some protocols use a sequence of six 0x00 or 0xFF for this purpose. Also, you may add a checksum to your commands. It will allow to distinguish the reset command from others.

Comment: @HelenDowns but how do I distuingish between the six bytes belonging to current data or reset? Even if I added a checksum, it could be a random pattern in a binary transmission, or am I missing a point?

Comment: @muffel, if your data may contain this sequence of bytes, then you should use timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may program the client to reset itself after a certain amount of time passed in a non-initial state with no incoming data. Upon restarting, the master would wait a slightly longer amount of time before sending the first command, thus guaranteeing that the client will be in the correct state at the beginning of the communication. You might also want to implement an initial status command sent upon (re)booting, to check if the previous transmission timed out or was correctly received.

If there is no shared clock source, you could either measure the timeout in UART bit times with a sufficient margin, or set a time-out a few orders of magnitude higher than that, for instance 1s.

However simple, this approach requires careful consideration if for any reason the application has stringent timing requirements that would be compromised by the wait performed as part of the master initialisation sequence.